# Is there a way to set wrapping to make the same amount of objects on each line in CSS

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have multiple items and I use flex-wrap to make design responsive.

```
#myList {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

While for the most part everything is fine, on certain situations i want to set it slightly different.
For example, on 6 items it wraps:

*1_2_3_4*

***5_6***

And i want to add some sort of priority of making the same amount of objects per line if its possible:

**1_2_3**

**4_5_6**

I didn't find solution with flex so far;

Comment: Do you know the number of items in advance or are you looking for a completely general solution? And what would be the desired result with say 7 or 8 items in the scenario you give?

Comment: I know amount of items in advance, but i don't know what overall container width will be since it depends on viewport. 
desired result should be for 6 items.
6-0; 
3-3;
2-2-2;
1-1-1-1-1-1 etc;